# Size of the GDK double buffer

Tags: c, buffer, cairo, clip

When (re)drawing CAIRO rectangles after an expose_event, I see that the double buffering prevents the screen from flickering.  Unfortunately when resizing the window frame the double buffer seems to "hang" on the screen as a shadow.  Setting double buffering to FALSE, removes the shadow but makes a complex drawing flicker.

If I would "invalidate" the complete newly resized window area (in the expose event), the problem is solved, but the expose event fires constantly new request to redraw.

How can I resize the GDK clip region in a double buffered context ?

thanks a lot

The program code I used detect the cause of problems :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean on_expose_event (GtkWidget *widget,
                                 GdkEventExpose *event ,
                                 gpointer data)
{
  cairo_t *cr;
  int width, height, kwadrant;

  cr = gdk_cairo_create (widget->window);

  gtk_window_get_size(GTK_WINDOW(widget), &width, &height);

  cairo_rectangle(cr, 0.0, 0.0, width, height);
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
  cairo_fill(cr);

  if (width < height)
      kwadrant = 0.8 * width;
  else
      kwadrant = 0.8 * height;

  cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1);
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  cairo_rectangle(cr, (width - kwadrant)/2, (height - kwadrant)/2, kwadrant, kwadrant);  
  cairo_stroke(cr);

  cairo_destroy(cr);

  return TRUE;
}

void frame_callback(GtkWindow *window,  
                    GdkEvent *event, 
                    gpointer data)
{

   char buff [50];
   sprintf (buff, "%i X %i", event->configure.width, 
                             event->configure.height);

   gtk_window_set_title(window, buff);
   return;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *darea;  

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), darea);

    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(window, TRUE);     
    gtk_widget_set_double_buffered(window, TRUE);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "expose-event",
                     G_CALLBACK(on_expose_event), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "configure-event",
                     G_CALLBACK(frame_callback), NULL);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",  
                             G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(window), GDK_CONFIGURE);

    gtk_widget_show (window);    
    gtk_main();    

    return 0;
}
```

========= added later :

As it often happens :
After searching for days for a valid solution, I posted this message.  A few moments afterwards I tried to isolate the "firing the clipping" outside the EXPOSE event and replace all

```
gtk_widget_queue_draw (widget);
```

calls with

```
void request_redraw (GtkWidget *widget)
{
    GdkRectangle rect;
    int width, height;

    gtk_window_get_size (GTK_WINDOW(window), &width, &height);

    rect.x      = 0;
    rect.y      = 0;
    rect.width  = width;    
    rect.height = height;   

    gdk_window_invalidate_rect (gtk_widget_get_window(widget), &rect, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_queue_draw (widget);

    return;
}
```

This allows me to keep the double buffering, avoid the flickering of the screen and to redraw the full area that corresponds with the resized frame/window.

Is this a correct solution or is there a better way ?

Sorry for having asked an unnecessary question